# Steam App on Wine fails to parse Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game even though required dlls are there

Tags: linux-mint, wine, steam

First question here, I'll include as much info as I can, but will be happy to provide more info if necessary. I've already searched both Google and SU, found many similar issues, attempted many suggested fixes (which is how I got to using the 32bit prefix and the installed components listed below) but to no avail.

**What am I trying to do?**

I'm trying to run the game 'Blood and Bacon' on Linux Mint using Wine.

**What's going wrong?**

The game won't run and throws an error. The pop-up says it can't find a suitable graphics card to support Direct3D.

edit: the Steam info tab shows it does find my graphics card

**Software used**

- Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
- Wine 1.6.2 (tried updating through terminal,
  but it tells me I have the newest version)

  - installed the following using winetricks:

    - d3dx10
    - d3dx9 (_26,_28,_31,_35,_36,_39,_42,_43)
    - directx9
    - dotnet40
    - xna40
- Steam (windows version)
- Blood and Bacon

**Hardware used**
CPU: AMD Athlon(tm) 7750 Dual-Core Processor
GPU:[AMD/ATI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
RAM: 4GB

When ran through Wine, Steam finds these correctly.

**Steps Taken**

- Created 32 bit prefix
- Installed Steam for Windows in said prefix, plus the above windows components
- Started Steam through terminal

`wine steam.exe -no-cef-sandbox -no-dwrite` (flags necessary to stop webhelper from crashing and to make text visible)

Installed Blood and Bacon through Steam (which went fine, no errors were shown) and selected it in the library, and hit 'play'. It shows up in my task manager, but uses no memory or cpu. The game doesn't actually start, although Steam shows I've played it for 37 minutes by now, so something is happening.

It throws a pop-up saying

`could not find direct3d device that supports the XNA framework HiDef profile` and goes on to state I need a proper graphics card, which I have, and which is detected by Steam as per the info tab.

When starting BloodanddBacon.exe directly through the terminal, it shows:

```
tijmen@tijmen-desktop ~/.wine-Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam $ wine "/home/tijmen/.wine-Steam/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steamapps/common/Blood and Bacon/BloodandBacon.exe"
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000380, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33fc04): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Steamworks.NET"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Microsoft.Xna.Framework"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Drawing"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Windows.Forms"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Accessibility"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Core"
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33cb78,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d9:D3DPERF_SetOptions (0x2) : stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0xbe6ad2, (nil), {8e9f5090-2d75-4d03-8a81-e5afbf85daf1}, 1, 0x33e474, (null), (null), 0xf44bc0,): stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
fixme:gdiplus:GdipCreateHalftonePalette stub
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
```

I don't use Wine that often, because I generally only use software that runs natively, but a few of my friends really want me to play this with them, so I'm making an exception. However, that means I'm not 100% confident in what I'm doing here, and I might be missing something really obvious.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just because the DLLs are there doesnt mean the game will work under Wine.  WineHQ shows no support at all for the game.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, however [others](https://steamcommunity.com/app/434570/discussions/0/351660338688425893/) have said it will work on Wine, so there must be some solution

Comment: Got news for you 1.6.5 isn't the current version of Wine it's 1.8.5.   You don't mention anything about your hardware.  Based on the error though  your version of Wine likely isn't detecting your hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound  Yes, Google told me there were more recent versions of Wine, but the only download I can find is the development version, which I find a bit risky due to my lack of experience w/ it. I'll update the question with my hardware

Comment: So download the source from Git and compile the binary?  Wondering why you installed DX10 when the game only requires DX9c which version would require a Windows machine to figure out.  I suggest using a free MS VM, install steam, then install the game and see not only what version of .net you need but what dx9c version it requires

Comment: I suppose I could do that. I don't have an awful lot of experience compiling software, but I can figure that out. Using an MS VM is an option, but I'd hoped somebody here might have figured it out already. Thanks for thinking along anyway. It's getting late here, so I guess I'll have to finish this tomorrow.

Comment: Figuring it out for you requires I purchase the game, it's a mobile game, mobile games are trash;  the Debian package is here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian I verified it has the current binary

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll see what I can get done using your link, and will update accordingly